# Store a object directly on ORM Laravel?

Tags: laravel-5, eloquent

I search for all the web and don't find a solution other than a custom function that we must make. I develops in Node.js and Laravel backend applications.

And in Node.js we send a object exactly equal to the database columns and we just use Sequelize insert function like this:

```
  async store(model) {
    try {
      await this.model.city.create(model);
    } catch (error) {
      throw error;
    }
  }
```

We simply use the same object that sending from the app we store like this **store(object);** and works fine.

In Laravel I always must reference the columns even so the objects have the same attributes from the columns on database, like this:

```
    $categoryObj = new Category;
    $categoryObj->name = $category['name'];
    $categoryObj->save();
    return $categoryObj;
```

I want to just make something like this:

```
    $categoryObj = new Category;
    $categoryObj = $category;
    $categoryObj->save();
    return $categoryObj;
```

It is possible?

Comment: What about Category::create($category) ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `create` method to insert a new record in the database.

```
class Category extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'table_name';
    protected $fillable = ['column_name_1', 'column_name_2', ...];
}
```

Then for inserting new data:

Example:

```
$model = YourModel::create([
    'field' => 'value',
    'another_field' => 'another_value'
]);
```

In your controller:

```
$categoryObj = new Category::create($category);
```

Also, you should look to Laravel's documentation: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent#mass-assignment

Comment: When i make this  $categoryObj = new Category::create($category); i get this syntax error, unexpected 'create' (T_STRING), expecting variable (T_VARIABLE) or '$'